# How to prevent shortcuts using Visio Drawing Control?

Tags: wpf, keyboard, visio, shortcut

I'm working with the VisioDrawingControl hosted, via WindowsFormsHost, in a WPF application.
What I want to do is to prevent the use of the shortcuts(such as CTRL+D, CTRL+Z, and so on), because I'm using different kind of shapes (Visio Stencils and CAD files) and some shortcuts do things that affect the application behaviour.

I've tried handling the MainWindow's keyup/keydown events (with eventargs.Handled = true), and deleting the correspondent AccelItems from DrawingControl.Window.Application.BuiltInMenus.AccelTables.

Even if I handle the MainWindow keyboard's events the VisioDrawingControl "captures" them and acts normally.
At last i've tried to undo the modifications from EnterScope and ExitScope events.
But still with no results.

Do you have some hints?